# auto delete inactive folders after x days

Tags: linux, console, debian

Is there a way I could delete certain folders after x amount of days of inactivity? i was thinking of using Crontab but that wouldn't take the inactivity part into consideration. are there any Debian Software out there that would do it? or is there a Linux Command that i am not aware of?

I've tried researching for something out there that could, but have had no luck.

any amount of help would be greatly appreciated.

also, I'm running Debian Wheezy at the moment.

thanks!

Comment: You might get better responses at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution might be this command:

`find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;`

Where you specify path to the files and +5 means that it will delete files older than 5 days.

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + T` will open you terminal.
then specify path like
find /home/yourusername/Documents/*

Comment: @David, `Ctrl+Alt+T` might open a terminal for *you*, but certainly not for me on my Debian/xfce system. anyhow, there are numerous ways to open a terminal.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I checked that. Anyway as you said there is a lot of ways to open terminal. And if you want you can event write a script to launch once a day, to delete folders.

Comment: @David could u possibly help me write that script please?